# solve system of two differential second order equations

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of two differential second-order equations in Matlab, using dsolve function, but got error because somehow, dsolve function does not convergent.

thats what i've tried to run:

```
syms x3(t) x2(t);
t=linspace(0,1,20);
sol=dsolve(10*diff(x2,2)==500000*(1-x2)+10000*(x3-x2)-1000*(diff(x3)-diff(x2))...
,350*diff(x3,2)==10000*(x2-1)-1000*(diff(x2)-diff(x3)),...
x2(0)==0,x3(0)==0);

sol=dsolve(diff(x3,2)==5+x2,diff(x2,2)==5+x3,diff(x3(0))==0,x2(0)==0)
x3=eval(vectorize(sol.x3))
x2=eval(vectorize(sol.x2))
[x3, x2]=dsolve(diff(x3,2)==5+x2,diff(x2,2)==5+x3,x3(0)==1)

s = dsolve(diff(x3,2)==5)
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: What error message do you get and which line raises the error?

Comment: it just get stuck, because it doesn't convergent

Comment: It's entirely possible that MATLAB is simply unable to solve your ODE.